# How to add acknowledgements on a separate page after abstract in apa7 documentclass man

Tags: acknowledgements, apa7

i am using

```
\documentclass[man, donotrepeattitle, floatsintext]{apa7}
```

to write my dissertation. I know, it is not the best class to write the dissertation in, but so far, all things worked as intended.

I am trying to add acknowledgements on a separate page after abstract, but nothing worked.

`\begin{acknowledgements}`, nor other things i tried.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why are you using manuscript-mode for a dissertation? doc is much better suited. Indeed you might just use some other class that is generally better suited for a dissertation (memoir?) and simply load biblatex with apa7 for citations. The apa style is only useful for drafts. You will get into all sorts of trouble trying to use it for a book.

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal working example, there is little we can do here. You could also have mentioned what you've tried so far. This way we won't suggest things that already didn't work for you.

## Edit

I've had a look at the package documentation. Apparently, you're supposed to use the `\authornote`-command for everything extra.

`\authornote{〈author-note〉}`: The Author Note, containing contact information, acknowledgements, etc.

It will appear *in front* of the abstract, though. I do not know much about apa style and document conventions, but I highly suspect that's how it's supposed to be.

So my **final answer** would be: Use the `\authornote`. If you can't be compelled to use it, have a look at the example below, which seems to do exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass[man, donotrepeattitle, floatsintext]{apa7}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa7} Package}
\author{Daniel A. Weiss}
\affiliation{A University Somewhere}
\leftheader{Weiss}

\abstract{This demonstration paper uses the \textsf{apa7} \LaTeX\ class to format the document in compliance with the 7th Edition ofthe American Psychological Assocation’s \textit{Publication Manual.} The references are managed using \textsf{biblatex}.}

\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage
\section{Aknowledgements}

\blindtext

\newpage

We begin with \textcite{Shotton1989}. 
We can also cite this work inparenthesis, like this: \parencite{Shotton1989}.

A three-author paper \parencite[e.g.,][]{Lassen2006} lists allthree authors for the first citation, then only the first authoron all subsequent citations \parencite{Lassen2006}.

Note the use of five heading levels throughout this demonstrationMethod section.

\section{Method}

\subsection{Participants}

We had a lot of people in this study.

\subsection{Materials}

Several materials were used for this project. 

Some of them werealready created for prior research.
\end{document}
```

[image: abstract]

[image: aknowledgements]